# Synchronuous Combination Lock

Tags: verilog, state-machines

I'm trying to implement a synchronous combination lock that will unlock once it receives "101011" using verilog. It has one input: x, and three outputs: unlock, ready, and error. Following these rules:

- In initial state ready=1. Remains in initial while x=0
- Upon receiving 101011 on x, unlock=1. Remains in unlock while x=1
- If in unlock state and x=0, will go to initial state
- In all states other than initial and unlock, if input on x doesn't advance the sequence (101011), error=1.
- Remain in error state while x=1. If x=0 in error state, go to initial state

From these rules I created the **state diagram** below (I labeled the initial state s_reset, since initial is 000000):
[image]
I've treated it like a sequence detector and just created a bunch of states. Here's my **code** below:

```
module lock
(
    input  wire      clock,
    input  wire      reset,
    input  wire      x,
    output reg      ready,
    output reg      unlock,
    output reg      error
);

  reg [2:0] state;
  reg [2:0] next_state;

  localparam s_reset=3'b000,
             s1=3'b001,
             s2=3'b010,
             s3=3'b011,
             s4=3'b100,
             s5=3'b101,
             open=3'b110, 
             s_error=3'b111;
             s_error=3'b111;

  always @ (posedge clock, posedge reset) begin
     if(reset)
      state <= s_reset;
    else
      state <= next_state;
  end

  always @ * begin
    case(state)
      s_reset : if(x==1'b1) begin 
                  next_state = s1; 
                  unlock = 1'b0;
                  ready = 1'b0;
                  error = 1'b0; 
                end
                else begin
                  next_state = s_reset;
                  unlock = 1'b0;
                  ready = 1'b1;
                  error = 1'b0; 
                end

      s1      : if(x==1'b0) begin 
                  next_state = s2; 
                  unlock = 1'b0;
                  ready = 1'b0;
                  error = 1'b0; 
                end
                else begin
                  next_state = s_error;
                  unlock = 1'b0;
                  ready = 1'b0;
                  error = 1'b1; 
                end

      s2      : if(x==1'b1) begin 
                  next_state = s3; 
                  unlock = 1'b0;
                  ready = 1'b0;
                  error = 1'b0; 
                end
                else begin
                  next_state = s_error;
                  unlock = 1'b0;
                  ready = 1'b0;
                  error = 1'b1; 
                end

      s3      : if(x==1'b0) begin 
                  next_state = s4; 
                  unlock = 1'b0;
                  ready = 1'b0;
                  error = 1'b0; 
                end
                else begin
                  next_state = s_error;
                  unlock = 1'b0;
                  ready = 1'b0;
                  error = 1'b1; 
                end

      s4      : if(x==1'b1) begin 
                  next_state = s5; 
                  unlock = 1'b0;
                  ready = 1'b0;
                  error = 1'b0; 
                end
                else begin
                  next_state = s_error;
                  unlock = 1'b0;
                  ready = 1'b0;
                  error = 1'b1; 
                end

      s5      : if(x==1'b1) begin 
                  next_state = open; 
                  unlock = 1'b0;
                  ready = 1'b0;
                  error = 1'b0; 
                end
                else begin
                  next_state = s_error;
                  unlock = 1'b0;
                  ready = 1'b0;
                  error = 1'b1; 
                end

      open    : if(x==1'b0) begin 
                  next_state = s_reset; 
                  unlock = 1'b1;
                  ready = 1'b0;
                  error = 1'b0; 
                end
                else begin
                  next_state = open;
                  unlock = 1'b1;
                  ready = 1'b0;
                  error = 1'b0; 
                end

      s_error  : if(x==1'b0) begin 
                  next_state = s_reset; 
                  unlock = 1'b0;
                  ready = 1'b1;
                  error = 1'b0; 
                end
                else begin
                  next_state = s_error;
                  unlock = 1'b0;
                  ready = 1'b0;
                  error = 1'b1; 
                end   

      default : begin
                  next_state = s_reset;
                  unlock = 1'b0;
                  ready = 1'b1;
                  error = 1'b0; 
                end
    endcase
  end   

endmodule
```

**Testbench** below

```
module testbench;                
    reg         clock;      // Free running clock
    reg         reset;      // Reset active high
    reg         x;          // Input - X
    wire        ready;      // Output - ready for combination
    wire        unlock;     // Output - unlocked
    wire        error;      // Output - error in combination

    initial begin
        $dumpfile( "dump.vcd" );
        $dumpvars;

        clock = 0;          // Set initial values for inputs 
        reset = 0;
        x = 0;              

        #1 reset = 1;
        #9 reset = 0;

        #30                 // Wait to make sure system is idle

        // Test good sequence
        x = 1;
        #10 x = 0;
        #10 x = 1;
        #10 x = 0;
        #10 x = 1;
        #10 x = 1;

        // Test to see if stays unlocked and then returns to ready
        #30 x = 0;

        // Test 1011 which should go into error on the fourth digit
        #30 x = 1;
        #10 x = 0;
        #10 x = 1;
        #10 x = 1;

        // Stay in error until x -> 0
        #30 x = 0;

        // Wait in ready and test error on a zero
        #30 x = 1;
        #10 x = 0;
        #10 x = 1;
        #10 x = 0;  

        #30 $finish;
    end

    always
        #5 clock = ~clock;

    lock u1
    (
        .clock( clock ),
        .reset( reset ),
        .x( x ),
        .ready( ready ),
      .unlock( unlock ),
        .error( error )
    );
endmodule
```

EDIT: Second always block changed to `always@*` now unlock and ready seem to be working, but error will equal one even if the sequence is correct. Waveform output shown below:
[image]

Comment: Not your issue, but for future reference, the `[2:0]` in the parameter declaration is pointless. Also for state machines you should be using `localparam` not `parameter` as they are not parameters that should be changed externally.

Comment: I thought the `[2:0]` wasn't doing anything, but saw it on another's code with a similar goal and thought that might've been my problem. Obviously not. Edited code: Removed `[2:0] `and switched `parameter` to `localparam`.

Comment: In the second always block `x` should be included in the sensitivity list. How do you test your module?

Comment: @tlb `always @ (state, next_state)` should be `always @*` (auto-sensitivity list). `always @ (state, next_state, x)` does work, but it requires you to remember to add all input to your sensitivity list for RTL and synthesized gates to be behaviorally equivalent.

Comment: @Greg changed it to be `always @*` but I'm still having problems with the error output... the waveform I'm getting has been added

Comment: you should flop your outputs. the combinational block should calculate the next_value of your output flops. E.g. `error <= next_error`

Comment: @Greg do you mean just switch the order ie: `next_state <= s_error` to `s_error <= next_state`? Because I get a "Net type cannot be used on the left side of this assignment" error when I do that.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your seeing glitchy behavior on the signals like `error` because they are pure combinational logic and the input and state-machine are out of phase. You should flop your outputs.

You can do something like this (as an example):

```
reg  next_ready;
reg  next_unlock;
reg  next_error;
always @ (posedge clock, posedge reset) begin
   if(reset) begin
    state  <= S_RESET;
    ready  <= 1'b0;
    unlock <= 1'b0;
    error  <= 1'b0;
  end
  else begin
    state  <= next_state;
    ready  <= next_ready;
    unlock <= next_unlock;
    error  <= next_error;
  end
end

always @* begin
  // default assignment
  next_ready  = 1'b0;
  next_unlock = 1'b0;
  next_error  = error; // <-- keeps previous values unless needed to be changed
  //
  case(state)
    S_RESET : begin
      if(x==1'b1) begin 
        next_state = S1; 
      end
      else begin
        next_state = S_RESET;
        next_ready = 1'b1;
      end
    end

    S1 : begin
      if(x==1'b0) begin 
        next_state = s2;
      end
      else begin
        next_state = S_ERROR;
        next_error = 1'b1; 
      end
    end

    ....

  endcase
end
```

I uppercased the parameters in my example to match with most coding guild-lines. This helps prevent confusing them with nets/variables.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing something, but it seems that a state machine is too complicated for this task.  Use a shift register with parallel out ([verilog borrowed](http://www.csit-sun.pub.ro/courses/Masterat/Xilinx%20Synthesis%20Technology/toolbox.xilinx.com/docsan/xilinx4/data/docs/xst/hdlcode8.html)):

```
module shift (C, SI, PO); 
input  C,SI; 
output [7:0] PO; 
reg [7:0] tmp; 

  always @(posedge C) 
  begin 
    tmp = {tmp[6:0], SI}; 
  end 
  assign PO = tmp; 
endmodule
```

Take the parallel out and compare it to your combination.  If you really want to add some state memory, you can add a reset input and some external logic to this, but a shift register seems like the clear starting point for solving this problem.  Simpler to debug as well.

Answer (score 0):

Due to comb logic output you have faced issues in error signal.. If you try to model your FSM using standard 3 always or 4-always block you wont observe this issue, of course with this it leads to utilization of Flip-Flops in FPGA which can be ignored. FSM coding style might be helpful to debug and readability.

```
  module lock (
        input  wire     clock,reset,x,
        output reg      ready,unlock,error
    );
    
  reg [2:0] state,next_state;

  localparam S_RESET = 3'd0,
             S1      = 3'd1,
             S2      = 3'd2,
             S3      = 3'd3,
             S4      = 3'd4,
             S5      = 3'd5,
             OPEN    = 3'd6,
             S_ERROR = 3'd7;

  always @ (posedge clock, posedge reset)
     if(reset)  state <= #1 S_RESET;
    else        state <= #1 next_state;

    always@* begin
            next_state = 'bx;
        case(state)
            S_RESET : next_state =  x ? S1      : S_RESET ;
            S1      : next_state = ~x ? S2      : S_ERROR ;
            S2      : next_state =  x ? S3      : S_ERROR ;
            S3      : next_state = ~x ? S4      : S_ERROR ;
            S4      : next_state =  x ? S5      : S_ERROR ;
            S5      : next_state =  x ? OPEN    : S_ERROR ;
            OPEN    : next_state = ~x ? S_RESET : OPEN    ;
            S_ERROR : next_state = ~x ? S_RESET : S_ERROR ;
        endcase
    end

  always @ (posedge clock, posedge reset)
     if(reset)  begin
                  unlock <= #1 1'b0;
                  ready  <= #1 1'b0;
                  error  <= #1 1'b0;
     end else begin
                  unlock <= #1 1'b0;
                  ready  <= #1 1'b0;
                  error  <= #1 1'b0;
        case(next_state)
            S_RESET : ready  <= #1 1'b1;
            OPEN    : unlock <= #1 1'b1;
            S_ERROR : error  <= #1 1'b1;
        endcase
     end
endmodule
```

output in vivado simulation
[image]